# S3 "Access Denied" to Bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, amazon-iam

I try to allow one of our Devs (myapp-dev1) the access to one explicit S3-Bucket.

1. I created a policy which should allow CRUD options (he should be able to write and read image files into that bucket, and only into this.

   ```
   "s3:PutObject",
   "s3:GetObject",
   "s3:DeleteObject",
   "s3:ListObjects"
   ```
2. I created a User named dev1 and assigned him to that new policy (the user is not in a Group nor has a Role)
3. I created a Bucket named accordingly `ARN: arn:aws:s3:::myapp-dev1-bucket`
4. Then in this bucket I switched to "Bucket Policy" and used the "Policy Generator" and allowed **every action** for that moment. All other settings failed so far, this one too. It looks like this:

   ```
   {
     "Id": "Policy123456789",
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
          "Sid": "Stmt123456789",
          "Action": "s3:*",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::myapp-dev1-bucket",
          "Principal": {
             "AWS": [
                 "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/myapp-dev1"
              ]
          }
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

But I still get an

> Excon::Error::Forbidden: Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)

- What I have done wrong?
- What I am missing?
- Does the User must also be allowed to list buckets?

Please help!

Comment: Is this bucket being used to serve images/assets or to serve a compiled single page application?

Comment: It’s used to serve Images, uploaded by the app through Carrierwave.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket_Name"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket_Name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```